# remove the last second character from string

Tags: c#, asp.net, substring

I had a query string end with :

```
where id in (.....,11,)
```

and I want to remove the last "," to work correct I try this :

```
string test = id_case[i];
id_case[i] = test.Substring(Math.Max(0,test.Length -2));
id_case[i] += test.Substring(Math.Max(test.Length-1,test.Length)) + ")";
```

but didn't work the whole " where .... " is disappear
any help ?

Comment: How is the comma-separated list generated?  Can it be removed there?

Comment: I tried to prevent it from adding to query but its not that easy 
because the code contain about seven update query in one string with about 30 case to update at the same time for each 

and came from repeaters ... so not that easy

Comment: My guess is that the string is generated with a loop that adds a comma to each string when a `string.Join` would have taken care of the last comma for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove the *last comma* in your query string:

```
var q = "where id in (.....,11,)";
q = q.Remove(q.LastIndexOf(','),1);
```

Comment: +1 - much cleaner, although you want `q.Remove(q.LastIndexOf(','),1);` to only remove one character.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be cleaner to remove the comma at the source, but one method is to do:

```
string[] parts = test.Split(',');
test = string.Join(",",parts.Take(parts.Length - 1))
     + parts[parts.Length-1);
```